# jQuery replace HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

In a portion of my code to get a "report view" where the element is different (textarea becomes a div or span) and use the same data with newlines I replace the new lines with page breaks.

Currently the function I use:

```
$.each($('[id^="mytext-text"]'),(i,e)=>{$(e).html($(e).html().replace(/\n/gm,'<br>'))})
```

I often find myself using this same format for replacing other things, i.e.,

```
$(e).text($(e).text+'more text');
```

Is there a better way (either about using line breaks or about the `.text(.text())`? I've seen suggestions to simply write your own function but I feel like that doesn't solve the generalized problem.

Comment: The argument to `.text()` and `.html()` can be a function. It receives the old text/html as an argument, and returns the replacement. You don't need `.each()`, since it automatically loops, and calls the function for each element.

Comment: Oh jeez I guess it pays to read the documentation once in a while; but I wouldn't have guessed I could apply a selector to each of the texts independently like you suggested without each. So this just becomes `$('[id^="mytext-text"]').text((i,e)=>e.replace(/\n/gm,'<br>'))` !

Comment: It should be `(e) =>`. The first argument is the old text.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function but it's not D: !

Comment: Oops, I misremembered.

Answer (score 1):

As [Barmar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37361/barmar) explained in his [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167413/jquery-replace-html#comment318871_167413), you can use the function as argument to [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). These methods iterate over all the elements matched by selector so, there is no need of `each`.

Also, `m`-multiline flag is not required in the regex and can be removed.

Final Code:

```
$('[id^="mytext-text"]').html((index, html) => html.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a jQuery function that takes the method name and a function something like this completely unverified code:

```
jQuery.fn.replace = function replace(methodName, replacerFunc) {
  return this.each(function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var originalValue = $this[methodName]();
    var newValue      = replacerFunc( originalValue);
    $this[methodName]( newValue ); 
  }
}
```

And then calling it something like:

```
$('my-selector').replace('html', (v) => v.replace(/\n/gm,'<br>') );
$('my-selector').replace('text', (v) => v + 'more text' );
```